# How to remove klarna/module-ordermanagement?

Tags: magento2, klarna

I want to remove klarna default modules from Magento 2 store,

```
composer remove klarna/module-ordermanagement
composer remove klarna/module-onsitemessaging
composer remove klarna/module-kp-graph-ql
composer remove klarna/module-kp
composer remove klarna/module-core
```

I tried the above command but it not working

Does anyone have an idea how we can remove it?

Comment: getting any error while removing..?

Comment: yes
 composer remove klarna/module-onsitemessaging
klarna/module-onsitemessaging is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
Dependency "symfony/finder" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly allowed. Ignoring.

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: @Pawan your answer is correct and working fine.

Comment: glad to know, it helped you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module can not removed directly from composer because not available in root `composer.json` `require` section.

First disable module i.e.

```
bin/magento module:disable Klarna_Ordermanagement Klarna_Onsitemessaging Klarna_KpGraphQl Klarna_Kp Klarna_Core
```

In the article https://www.integer-net.com/removing-unused-core-modules-from-magento-2-the-right-way/ we can remove by adding `replace` node.

We an utilize `replace` in composer.json like:

```
 "replace": {
    "klarna/module-ordermanagement": "*",
    "klarna/module-onsitemessaging": "*",
    "klarna/module-kp-graph-ql": "*",
    "klarna/module-kp": "*",
    "klarna/module-core": "*"
}
```

After that we need to run `composer update`

[image]

**Note:** Add `replace` node after `require` section